# Generic Preprocessor adds extra whitespace

Tags: compiling, whitespace, markdown

Following up on [this article](http://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/) I use [GPP](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP) to empower Markdown parser [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) with some macros. Unfortunately, `gpp` seems to copy all whitespace into the result.

For example, consider file `test.md`

```
% Title
% Raphael
% 2012

\lorem \ipsum
```

with `test.gpp`

```
\define{lorem}{Lorem}
\define{ipsum}{ipsum...}
```

Now, calling `gpp -T --include test.gpp test.md` yields

```
<empty line>
% Title
% Raphael
% 2012

Lorem ipsum...
```

This breaks the metadata extraction of `pandoc`. The extra linebreak is indeed the one between the definitions; if I use

```
\define{lorem}{Lorem}@@@
\define{ipsum}{ipsum...}
```

with the extra option `+c "@@@" "\n"`, the empty line is gone. But this workaround is not only ugly, is also has two fatal flaws.

First, it treats `@@@` as comment indicator in the source file, too. As `@@@` is not forbidden in Markdown, that can have unintended consequences when `@@@` (or any other chosen delimiter) happens to occur in the source file.

Second, it does not cover whitespaces at line beginnings as caused by proper indentation. For example,

```
\define{lorem}{@@@
  \if{a == a}@@@
    ![some image](test.png)@@@
  \endif@@@
}@@@
```

will cause all such image tags to be indented by four spaces, causing `pandoc` to typeset it as code (as specified).

So, short of writing `gpp` files in one line or introducing ugly line-end comments and not indenting, what can you do to prevent `gpp` from plastering superfluous whitespaces all over the place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the junk is in the include file, and therefore before the start of the document, you could just post-process it:

test.gpp:

```
\define{lorem}{Lorem}
\define{ipsum}{ipsum...}
----- cut here ------
```

Then do:

```
gpp -T --include test.gpp test.md | sed '1,/----- cut here ------/d'
```

(Does `gpp` output to stdout? Otherwise just run `sed` on the output file.)

Comment: That's nice for the "static" junk from the include file. It doesn't fix the "dynamic" indentation problem, or does it? (`gpp` does output to stdout by default, yes.)

Comment: I used your answer, added some more brute force and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to preprocess the included macro file and shrink it to one line (using `sed`). In combination with [ams approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46503/17409), this makefile fragment solves the problem:

```
sed 's/^\s*//;s/\s*?$$//;H;$$!d;:e;x;/^$$/d;s/\n//g' $(MACROFILE) > $(BUILDPATH)/$(MACROFILE);
echo "$(MFENDMARKER)" >> $(BUILDPATH)/$(MACROFILE);

gpp -T -x -Dtarget=pdf --include $(BUILDPATH)/$(MACROFILE) $(MAINFILE) | \
  sed '1,/$(MFENDMARKER)/d' | \
  pandoc -S -R --toc -f markdown -o $(DISTPATH)/$(NAME).pdf;
```

Now the nastiness is hidden behind the scenes.

Comment: What is MFENDMARKER?

Comment: @aggsol  It's been a while; from its usage here, an arbitrary (but unique?) end marker for the macro file. Not sure why it is needed.